# Can I renew a driver's licence online ( can I send a photo via email?) in Texas?

Tags: driving-license

The problem is the following. I need to change my driver's license photo, is there still a way to get it done online or I have to fly back to U.S?
Can I send them a photo via email or something?

Answer (score 1):

I searched online for "renew Texas drivers license." A list of results was presented, including [this page](https://www.dmv.org/tx-texas/renew-license.php#Renewal-Options-Instructions) from Texas DMV. Midway down the page, "Out of State Renewal" was discussed. Here's the information (copied-and-pasted) from that section:

To renew your TX driver's license by mail, download the Out-of-State or Out-of-Country Packet (Form DL-16P) and submit the documents included:

A completed:

- Application for Out of State or Out of Country Renewal/Replacement/Change of Texas Driver License or Identification Card (Form DL-16). Include your Texas address.
- Exemption Certification for Class A or B Non-CDL Supplement to Texas Driver License Application (Form CDL-2), if you are renewing a Class A or Class B driver's license.
- Explanation for Eye Specialist (Form DL-63), if your last renewal
  wasn't done in person.
- Payment for your renewal fee. (See the Renewal Fees in TX section
  below.)

The page refers to Form DL-16, which is easily downloaded or viewed. This form contains further info about out of state renewal: for example, the applicant must have their "true, fixed, and permanent home (domicile)" in Texas.

However, license photographs are not mentioned, and no provision appears for submitting a new one. That indicates that Texas uses only the photographs taken at Texas DMV offices, and no others.

Thus, the only way to obtain a new drivers license photograph is to personally appear at a Texas DMV office.